# color.xml code is missing from every android studio project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, colors

my color.xml file of every project is missing it only show error without any single line of code. I am newbie in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it by your own if it does not exist in your project.
Right click on res->values folder, make a new file named colors.xml and define your color as following in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution, this helps for me.

Comment: Kindly upvote answer if it worked for you, It will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

see in android studio at the top most right side, there is search button.
just click on it and search for colors.xml
It will show up the file, it is always there sometimes it just doesn't comes